# Out of range jquery error

Tags: jquery

I keep getting a out of range error. I thought that the problem was that I was including jquery library in two places but I'm not.

Well I downloaded this jquery scrollbar 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/index.htm

Put it on my home folder and call it with a really simple HTML file.
*
*
*

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="facescroll.js">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ // on page DOM load
      $('#demo1').alternateScroll({'hide-bars':false});
    })
 </script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="demo1"  style="width:470px; height:485px; overflow:scroll;float: left;overflow-x: hidden;">
  <iframe height="" width="455px" key="1" id="fone" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com" ></iframe>
</div>
```

The code sometimes execute fine sometime doesnt the facescroll.js library is this one:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/index.htm

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getting a 403 on your library.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in the library?